# Wordpress WpForm customize submit button to call external API (Json)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I wanted to change the submit button to be able to trigger ajax or whatever that can send POST request to another server (as I wanted to managed all data submit from wordpress in another server). Wordpress is just simple UI page with webform to create a record and send over to another server. I have no knowledge on PHP at all. How can I managed to modify the code in order to achieve it? Don't Worry about CORS issue as I can handle that

Comment: Are you using a plugin WPForms ? and can you specify that you want to send all the recorded data to another server. Is your other server based on php or have an endpoint where data can be recieved ?

Comment: @UsmanMunir, Yes it is WPForms plugin, My other server based on Java and consists of endpoint to get data and save in the database. I had seen a few plugin like formidable forms etc. Those required to upgrade premium. Please advise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you need.

In your theme functions.php file you need to add this WPForms action this will trigger when you complete and submit the form.

```
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'sendingDataToJava', 10, 4 );

   function sendingDataToJava( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id) {
    
    //Specify WPForm ID you have there

    //if form ID is 1 (checking index id of $form_data array)
    if ($form_data['id'] == 1) {
        
      $api_url = 'http://some java end point.com';
      $body = array(
        'name'                => $fields['1']['value'],
        'email'               => $fields['2']['value'],
        'phone'               => $fields['3']['value'],

       );
       $request = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
        
     }
}
```

You will have to see the $fields id's in the form your using and change above accordindly. Also you need to figure to check how to get the data on your java end point file.

**Another Way**

Another way will be an ajax request by adding this action in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_foobar', 'sendingDataToJava' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_foobar', 'sendingDataToJava' );
function sendingDataToJava() {
    // do something
    
    // avoids extra 0 at the end of the response
    die(); /
}
```

In your theme JS file add this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $('#form_button_id').click( function() {
      
      //
      var data = {
         name: $('#field_1').val(),
         email: $('#field_2').val(),
         phone: $('#field_3').val()
      };

      var ajaxurl = 'http://some java end point.com';
      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         alert('Data Sent to Sent +' response);
      }
      );
   }
   );
}
);
```

Refer to this WPForm action for more info: https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_complete/

Hope this helps

Comment: do this: $request = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array( 'body' => $body,  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8')  ) );